# System.InvalidOperationException - ( последовательность не содержит элементов ). Как решить проблему?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Хочу создать возможность редактирование модели. *Сама ошибка:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Home Controller:**

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        BookContext db = new BookContext();
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {


            return View(db.Books.First());
        }

        [HttpPost]

        public ActionResult Index(Book book)
        {
            db.Entry(book).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        //https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/5.5.php

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
```

**Index.cshtml:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/_Layout.cshtml";
}


@model justfortest.Models.Book

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <fieldset>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, "Название книги")
            <br />
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Author, "Автор")
            <br />
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Author)

        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Price, "Цена")
            <br />
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Price)
        </p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить" /></p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

**Book Context:**

```
    public class BookContext: DbContext
{
    public BookContext() : base("BookContext")
    { }

    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Purchase> Purchases { get; set; }

}
```

Web.Config:
Использую MS SQL  2014:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BookContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename='|DataDirectory|\BookStore.mdf';Integrated Security=True"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Модели созданы. В БД данные существуют.

Comment: используйте метод `.FirstOrDefault()` вместо `.First()` в методе `Index`

Comment: "В БД данные существуют" - это прекрасно, но вот получает ли ваш код эти данные? Видимо нет, раз не может выдать первый элемент.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

используйте метод .FirstOrDefault() вместо .First() в методе Index